# Jasper Report Security Sandboxing

Tags: security, jasper-reports, reporting, sandbox

I am writing a Java web app which I would like to allow users to execute basic PDF reports. Normally I would use Jasper Reports for this. However this time I would like the users to be able to edit there own reports in iReport and upload them. Which should be straight forward enough.

That got me thinking, Jasper lets you effectively write code in the reports which gets executed when the report is generated. Is it possible to write a report which has full access to the Java API and therefore my web app. I don't want users being able to kill tomcat or worse still use the DAO api I have built to read other users data.

Does any one know if this is actually possible and if so can you sandbox it somehow. May be I could filter the reports XML before its complied some how?

Also does anyone know if the same applies to other open source reporting tools such as BIRT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the java-sandbox [1] which we use in our BI solution Reportserver [2]. I am currently preparing a blog-post which will explain how to run jasperreports in a sandboxed environment.

As for Birt, the very same applies there too. Here user's cannot directly write java code, but they can use Rhino which in the end has the same effect.

[1] http://blog.datenwerke.net/p/the-java-sandbox.html
[2] http://reportserver.datenwerke.net

Answer (score 2):

I'm releasing a web service [1] to allow developers to generate PDF using templates drawn on i-report,

So I had to solve the same problem, my first try was to use the Java Security Engine API, but it was too complex with a lot of required permissions.

So while I was searching how Heroku isolates each web app, I discovered the Linux Containers (LXC) [2], so i decided to isolate each "developer sandbox" in a lxc container.

It don't prevent users to shutdown the "sandboxed server", but if they do, they will power off only its own sandbox, other users sandbox won't be affected.

[1] http://reports.simpleservic.es/landing
[2] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC

Comment: Not the ideal solution as it will require DAO access to be made remote and secured.  But I'm not seeing any other alternatives.

Comment: In my case, the service supports XML as datasource, instead of SQL datasource, so no data base access is required.